# MEF not providing object

Tags: c#, mef

Update:

This is an mvc plugin project, using MEF to get the controllers and actions at run time. http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=104

I added a new project and in its class I added an export of a type that is already being composed.

```
  [Export(typeof(IController)), ExportMetadata("Name", "Clocks")]
  public class ClocksController : Controller
  {

    public XmlActionResult Index()
    {
     var p = DeviceLogic.GetUnassigned;
    }
  [Import(typeof(DeviceLogic))]
  DeviceLogic DeviceLogic { get; set; }
  }
```

This gets composed in another project:

```
  [Export]
  public class ImportControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
  {
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<PartFactory<IController, IControllerMetadata>> ControllerFactories;
  }
```

Application Start

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<ImportControllerFactory> ControllerFactories;
```

Controller factories is null, until I actually compose the parts

```
container.ComposeParts(this);
```

thats working fine, so I decided to try and emulate this to get devicelogic to appear in the project im having trouble with.

I created an emptry interface (IEmpty) for testing and tried this:

```
  [Export(typeof(IEmpty))]
  public class RequestProcessor : IEmpty
  {

    [Import(typeof(DeviceLogic))]
    DeviceLogic DeviceLogic { get; set; }
  }
```

and in my applciation start added

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<IEmpty> TestMef;
```

This is filled with the one instance after composition, so this seems to have worked. My question is does anyone have any suggestions as to why devicelogic is null in requestprocessor but not in clocksController.

Comment: Can't you add the parts where you create the catalog(s) and container as well as the code for the composition of dataTransfer? Also are the types in the same assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call MEF's `SatisfyImportsOnce` method after your instantiation :

```
YourMEFContainter.SatisfyImportsOnce(dataTransfer)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am doing that. I can see the container and it has all the exports I would expect. thansk for the reply

Comment: So you also have a catalog already ?
May I know where your `SatisfyImports` call is ?

Comment: Sorry Luke, I misread. I have the catlogue and the container and other MEF loads are working perfectly. I dont use SatisfyImports - Is this a 4.5 thing?

Comment: I read somewhere that when you manually instantiate an object that has an imported property, you need to call `SatisfyImports(objectThatNeedsImports)`

Comment: That sounds promising. Ill do a bit of reading. Thansk for the ehads up.

Comment: Tell me if you find something helpful :)

Comment: @LukeMarlin SatisfyImports is for Silverlight. SatisfyImportsOnce is the one for .NET Framework. SatisfyImportsOnce is just for parts where recomposition should be turned off.

Comment: This article describes how to do this for WPF: http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/02/prism-4-mef-and-the-compositioninitializer/